# Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative distribution function $F_X$, find $F_Y$ for $Y = \sin(X)$ and $Y = \cos(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with continuous cumulative distribution function $F_X$, find $F_Y$ for $Y = \sin(X)$ and $Y = \cos(X)$

My approach:

- I would say that $F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = 1$ for $y \in [1, \infty)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = 0$ for $y \in (-1, \infty)$. For both cases of $Y$

But I can't figure out what $F_Y(y)$ for $y \in [-1, 1)$ in both cases is.

Comment: You're solving the inequality $\sin(x) \leq y$ where $y \in [-1,1)$. It's a bit ugly because you have to deal with all of the "copies" of the circle. Can you write out how you would do it if $X$ were entirely concentrated on $[0,2\pi]$? Then maybe we can help you with the copies of the circle.

Comment: I don't see how I can rewrite this on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, maybe I can consider $y \in (-1, 1)$?

Comment: You can't rewrite your original problem so that $X$ is confined to $[0,2\pi]$, but that is a special case that you can solve more easily than the general case.

Comment: Yes I got that, but I don't see how. I don't see either what is special about this case

Comment: Well, if $X$ is entirely in $[0,2\pi]$ and, say, $y>0$ then $\{ \sin(X) \leq y \}=\{ 0 \leq X \leq \arcsin(y) \} \cup \{ \pi-\arcsin(y) \leq X \leq 2 \pi \}$.

Comment: Therefore $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \left[F_X(\arcsin(y)) - F_X(0) \right] \cup \left[F_X(2\pi) - F_X(\pi - \arcsin(y) \right] $? for $Y = \sin(X)$.

Comment: Well, $+$, not $\cup$, and you need the caveats I said, but otherwise yes.